# When did "almuerzo" and "desayuno" stop being synonyms, and why?

Tags: definiciones, historia, comida

We can see in the answers to [Why would "breakfast" be translated as "lunch"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12808/why-would-breakfast-be-translated-as-lunch) that, up until at least the end of s. XIX, *almuerzo* and *desayuno* were proper synonyms.

Nowadays, however, to most people they mean different meals (the most common distinction is, I think, that *desayuno* is had first thing in the morning, i.e. a breakfast, and *almuerzo* is kind of a second breakfast, closer to midday).

When did this distinction appear?
And why did we set on "desayuno" being the earlier one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only answer the 2nd question. The verb *desayuno* is so common that we don't realize it is *des-**ayunar***.

From the DLE:

> *[**ayunar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4cYY5ZV)
>
>   1. Abstenerse total o parcialmente de comer o beber.*

In *desayunar*, '*des-*' is the negative prefix (which also appears in the DLE, and it's interesting on its own). **The first time you eat something, you stop the *ayuno*, so *desayuno* is necessarily the first meal of the day**.

It's funny that we say "*Hoy no he desayunado*" all day long when we skip breakfast, when originally that sentence would only be valid until your first meal, which would then become your *desayuno* even if it's 6pm. However, nowadays it has obviously linked its meaning to "the meal of the early morning".

By the way, *ayunar* is "to fast" in English. When you eat something, you're breaking your fast. Hence "breakfast".

Comment: Y yo preguntándome por qué porras los ingleses cuando desayunan dicen que "rompen rápido"...

Comment: lol, asi es @Charlie , Fast o Fasting es como se le llama a la practica de ayunar